# What does "pc group" mean in GAP?

Tags: group-theory, definition, gap

For example, when I enter `G:=CyclicGroup(2);` in GAP, the program returns with the information `<pc group of size 2 with 1 generators>`.

Question: What does "pc group" mean in the above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It stands for ["polycyclic group (presentation)"](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap46.html#X7EAD57C97EBF7E67).

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1553693) may also be of interest.

If you want to inspect the underlying presentation of the group, one way to do this is as follows:

```
gap> G:=CyclicGroup(2);
<pc group of size 2 with 1 generators>
gap> H:=Image(IsomorphismFpGroup(G));
<fp group of size 2 on the generators [ F1 ]>
gap> RelatorsOfFpGroup(H);
[ F1^2 ]
```

This presentation does not necessarily have a minimal possible number of generators - its generators should satisfy different conditions, what makes algorithms to work with such groups very efficient. For example,

```
gap> G:=DihedralGroup(8);
<pc group of size 8 with 3 generators>
gap> H:=Image(IsomorphismFpGroup(G));
<fp group of size 8 on the generators [ F1, F2, F3 ]>
gap> RelatorsOfFpGroup(H);
[ F1^2, F2^-1*F1^-1*F2*F1*F3^-1, F3^-1*F1^-1*F3*F1, F2^2*F3^-1, 
  F3^-1*F2^-1*F3*F2, F3^2 ]
```

In some cases, `SimplifiedFpGroup` can help to get a more human-readable presentation:

```
gap> S:=SimplifiedFpGroup(H);
<fp group on the generators [ F1, F2 ]>
gap> RelatorsOfFpGroup(S);
[ F1^2, F2^4, (F1*F2)^2 ]
```

and this is indeed what one would expect to see for $D_8$.

Comment: That is correct, but I think it means slightly more than that. It means a polycyclic group that is defined by a polycyclic presentation, which is a particular type of presentation (confusingly often called a *power-conjugate* or *power-commutator* presentation) that is well adapted to structural computations within the group.

Comment: Thank you, @DerekHolt. I have made a slight adjustment.

Comment: In addition to @DerekHolt 's remark, there used to be two slighly different standards of writing down such a presentation (namely *power-commutator* and *power-conjugate*) and the name *PC* was adopted to make this difference irrelevant (and to allude to polycyclicity).

Comment: In addition, you can enter `?pc group` in GAP to see the documentation on Pc Groups (see more on how to use GAP help [here](https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/gap-lesson/01-command-line/index.html)).

Comment: As this question was closed for not being about maths, I think it would be beneficial if your answer could be made more maths-ey, e.g. explaining what power-commutator and power-conjugate presentations are, and how they relate to polycyclic groups.

Comment: @user1729 I think the link to the GAP manual explains that adequately - and the question has now been re-opened.

Comment: @DerekHolt Making the maths more prominent would hopefully help the question not be closed again. Also, relying on links isn't great (due to link rot).

Comment: @user1729 It probably won't be closed again - I wonder what's the record on MSE for the number of times a question has been closed and re-opened. The probelm is that writing out the definition of polycyclic/power-commutator/power-conjugate presentation would involve tedious effort! I have added another link to a related question.

Comment: Thank you for the edits, everyone! :)

Comment: H.H. Just to add for the future that if some question is closed, there is no need to delete it - the discussion in the comments, or even answers, if given, may have useful inputs for other visitors of this site, and represents certain efforts of other participants of the discussion. And the question may be edited to be reopened, as happened here.