# What is the most efficient way of storing group information? How does GAP do it?

Tags: group-theory, gap, cayley-table

What is the most efficient way of storing the information contained in group's Cayley table on a disk? Cayley tables grow with $|G|^2$, and for some orders ($p^k$ for growing $k$) there are just too many of them.

For example, there are $10494213$ groups (up to isomorphism) of order $512$. Assuming we need 2 bytes per element of the Cayley table, storing all groups of order $512$ alone would require 5.5TB of memory!

How does GAP's SmallGroups library circumvent this problem? I tried looking through its [source code](https://github.com/gap-packages/smallgrp), but I only found some cryptic lists of integers used to describe the group

```
SMALL_GROUP_LIB[ 16 ] := [
    149511, 9219, 16905, 279051, 9221, 140301, 2245212, 35922525, 574759519, 513, 520, 139787, 8716, 0
];
```

**TL;DR:** I am looking for a way to store Cayley table information on disk more efficiently. Anything that can be used to reconstruct the Cayley table in reasonable (say polynomial) time would be of great help.

Comment: Cayley tables are a very inefficient way to store group information and are not used by software systems. Solvable groups are stored by PC-presentations and non-solvable groups as permutation groups (or matrix groups for very large finite groups). In fact for the small groups library in GAP, more sophisticated methods of compression are used. For the orders such as 1536 with very large numbers of groups, large families whose members that depend on a couple of parameters can be stored as a single entity. Why would you want store a Cayley table anyway?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/a/15095/88984

Comment: This "cryptic list of integers" are encoded PC-presentations. See [this chapter](https://docs.gap-system.org/doc/ref/chap46.html#X874E4B107BD78F5A) of the GAP manual for more information.

Comment: Did you really believe that the COMPLETE Cayley table of EVERY those groups are stored in GAP ? We can of course recover the structure of a group with much less information , and of course GAP makes use of this possibility.

Comment: About PC-presentations in GAP: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4203293/305862

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you. I do not want to store the Cayley table itself, but I need to be able to reconstruct it (for a machine-learning application).

Comment: About pc-presentations in GAP mentionned by Derek Holt, see for example here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4203293/305862

Comment: El := Elements(G);; n := Size(G);; List([1..n], i->List([1..n], j->Position(El,El[i]*El[j]))); will produce the Cayley table of a group $G$ in GAP.

Comment: I think in GAP a matrix group over a finite field is stored by its generators. So to store $G \leq GL(n,q)$ generated by $G = \langle A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_k \rangle$ you just need to store $k$ matrices of size $n \times n$.  For example $GL(n,q) = \langle A, B \rangle$ for certain matrices $A$ and $B$. Easier to store e.g. $GL(3,11)$ as just two matrices rather than with a set of $|GL(3,11)| = 2124276000$ matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cayley table is easily recreated (see Derek Holt's comments) once you have generators and a way of representing elements in a unique way.

A group of order $n$ requires at most $\log_2(n)$ generators, though often one can do with fewer.

As for representing elements uniquely, this is obvious if you have a faithful permutation or matrix representation, but these can be of degree $|G|$ in worst case.

What the small groups library in GAP does for solvable groups (most of them) is to use a particular *presentation*, that is words in generators with a way to bring them into normal forms, called *pc presentation*.

The numbers you see in the storage then are just a particular way (similar to zip files) of storing the data for such a presentation.